# I've got Internal Error whilst running a Ubuntu Beta. How to gather information and find out what it is?

Tags: bug-reporting, system-info, error-handling

Today, I was running the Ubuntu Beta (Ubuntu 12.04) and it experienced an internal error.

I know I should file a [bug report](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

However, I want to go check more detailed in the log files, but where are they located on my system?

Although, i didn't enable core dump before. I just checked, there is no core dump file right now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bug reporting is something Ubuntu is seriously good at. When you see that dialog, Ubuntu has already collected all the relevant information for you, so all you need to do, is to click "Show Details".

**You'll first see a dialog like this:**

[image]

**Or like this:**

[image]

**Then clicking 'Show Details' will display more details.**

[image]

**That will collect data from all the relevant files** and if you click "Continue" while the checkbox is checked, you'll automatically upload it to Launchpad.net, which will scan for similar reports, allow you to add to an existing report or to create a new one.

Particularly during development, you might be told that you can't report bugs because you have software that is out of date.

Comment: Good answer for the desktop system, but I'm getting a bug in the beta release of the latest server edition. (Don't worry, I'm not asking a question, passing a comment, but if you'd like to expand you're answer to include problems with the server edition... :) +1 anyway

Comment: I don't really have time, but if you run "man apport-bug", you'll get a good explanation. If you have time, it would be nice if you could add your own answer when you feel comfortable. :)

Comment: I know I'm more comfortable than others, but I'm in no way comfortable with my own terminal knowledge. That was why I came here in the first place. I'm so desperate to learn more about what goes on behind the scenes. I'm so sick of getting stuck at what I often feel like are little things :/ Ahh well, thinking positive, I will get there. :) Cheers.

Comment: The command simply opens a text document, the manual for apport-bug. If you have an Ubuntu desktop, you can do the same thing by opening man:apport-bug in your browser. You'll probably have to confirm that you wish to open it using Help.